# Pgfplot - Compiling with Luatex - Problem with standalone class

Tags: luatex

I am trying to plot a huge data set. When I tried to compile this with `PDFLatex`, this gave me memory issues. So I decided to compile this with `Luatex`. This is giving me error messages which I don't understand fully.

> ! Undefined control sequence.\sa@placebox ->\newpage \global\pdfpagewidth=\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh... \end{document}
>
> ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.= \end{document}
>
> ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.= \end{document}
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.\sa@placebox...wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageheight=\ht \sa@box \global \pape...\end{document}
>
> ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='.= \end{document}
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.\global \end{document}
>
> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).\global \end{document}

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{15cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{15cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale only axis}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump,
xtick pos=left,
ytick pos=left,
  xlabel= $\omega_r$,
  ylabel= $\omega_i$,
  legend columns=-1,
  legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.25cm}},
  xmin=-1000, xmax=3000,
  ymin=-200, ymax=100,
  xtick={-1000,-500,0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000} 
  ]
\addplot [only marks, color=blue,mark size=1.5] table [x index=0, y index =1] {e50_full.dat};
\addplot [only marks, color=black,mark size=1.5] table [x index=0, y index =1] {e55_full.dat};

\addlegendentry{$50\times50$}
\addlegendentry{$55\times55$}
        

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here are the data [set 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yge7s0dm8g99n47/e50_full.dat?dl=0), [set 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zbs0cfp28qcr4o/e55_full.dat?dl=0)

What is going wrong here?

Edit:

I solved the issue following pschulz's suggestion by changing from `standalone` class to `article`. The problem still persists for `standalone` class. Why is that so?

Comment: Could you please integrate a minimal extract from the data in your MWE?

Comment: As @TeXnician mentioned, your MWE is not really a MWE. Remove all the comments, the unused packages (all except `pgfplots`). Then, you can also strip down your data. Then you can see if this is the problem. For me, it is not. I can compile your example by not using the `standalone` class but e.g. `article`. Which class are you using? Make a *real life* MWE, best to start with your real document and throw everything away not needed. This is also the best debugging routine.

Comment: Also, half of your data is garbage (only Inf in x and y), so you can strip it down, this should relax memory constraints.

Comment: @pschulz Thanks for the suggestion. I face no problem with class `article` and the code compiles fine now. But the problem still persists with `standalone` class. I'm curious to know why .

Comment: I see that. Sorry, i can't help you with that, i don't know much about the standalone class. Perhaps you should rephrase your question, in order to attract the curiosity of the gurus ;)

Comment: you should put error log in a code section `{}` not quote `"` as line ends inportant but the issue is just that you need `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as the first line as standalone has still not been updated for current luatex.